# Monodevelop and call stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, monodevelop

In monodevelop-in operating system Linux Ubuntu execute the following code:

```
konekcija_cela.Open()
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Vrati", konekcija_cela)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure            
Try
Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim ds As New DataSet
adapter.Fill(ds, "sluzbe") 
konekcija_cela.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
msgbox(ex)
End Try
```

I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of
range.
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillTable (System.Data.DataTable dataTable,
IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, System.Int32&
counter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillInternal (System.Data.DataTable
dataTable, IDataReader dataReader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataTable dataTable,
IDataReader dataReader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataTable dataTable,
IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

and when instead of calling the procedure, execute the following code, it works well:

```
con.Open()
Dim cmd1 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT    * FROM  nekatabela",   con) 
Dim adapter1 As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
Dim ds1 As New DataSet
adapter1.Fill(ds1, "tabela")
con.Close()
```

Is this a bug or something else? Of course both parts of the code have been
tested on Windows OS and doing great.If anyone has any advice or suggestion.
Thank you !

Comment: what is the database?

Comment: Stored procedures is on MS SQL

Comment: cant install `ms sql` on `linux`.  
you can access to installed `ms sql` in virtual machine or server i think.

Comment: The MS SQL server is on anither machine ( Windows Server ). when I access stored procedures on MS SQL get error on this part    adapter.Fill(ds, "sluzbe") ...